# logstash grok patterns assistance

Tags: grok

I really need some help parsing the below log and matching with grok

> Mar 19 17:23:12:00 Alert - Traffic Gap Detected - severity[Alert] source[Text1/Text2] reason[MajorSet] count[1] value[1]

I want similar to this:

> timesamp:Mar 19 17:23:12:00
>
> Alert: Alert - Traffic Gap Detected -
>
> severity: Alert
>
> source:Text1/Text2
>
> reason:MajorSet
>
> count:1
>
> value:1

```
grok{ 
    match => [ "message" => "%{SYSLOGTIMESTAMP:timestamp} %{GREEDYDATA: Alert - Traffic Gap Detected} %{WORD:severity]"]
}
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

Something like this can parse your log line:

```
%{SYSLOGTIMESTAMP:timestamp} %{GREEDYDATA:alert} - severity\[%{WORD:severity}\] source\[%{DATA:source}\] reason\[%{DATA:reason}\] count\[%{NUMBER:count}\] value\[%{NUMBER:value}\]
```

You can test it here: https://grokdebug.herokuapp.com/